# Command 'export' not recognized after 'npm run build' with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

We want to use webpack in our project. It has already been partly integrated as a test on a Mac and it works.
When using the same branch on my Windows machine I get following error message.

Webpack version ist 1.12.15

The part in German means that command 'export' could not be recognized or was not written correctly.

```
S:\project>npm run build

> project@version build S:\project
> export NODE_ENV=dev && webpack

Der Befehl "export" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\someone\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v4.4.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! project@version build: `export NODE_ENV=dev && webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project@version build script 'export NODE_ENV=dev && webpack'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the onedata package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     export NODE_ENV=dev && webpack
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs project
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls project
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     S:\project\npm-debug.log
```

It is not possible to use the newest node.js, as some other packages are incompatible to it.

Comment: `export` is used in `unix` family(Linux, Mac, etc) while you need to use **`set`** in the place of `export` in windows

Comment: @ArifKhan is right. `npm run build` will execute the build script defined into the `package.json` file. According to this output, this run script runs `export NODE_ENV=dev && webpack` which are supposed to be run on UNIX (at least for the `export` part).

Comment: You may try [this approach](http://jonnyreeves.co.uk/2016/simple-webpack-prod-and-dev-config/) to replace `export`. I suspect it should work both on Windows and UNIX-based OS (but I don't have Window so I cannot test it).

Comment: Strange enough, when I run `export` in a git-bash on Windows, it works, but when this command is run from an npm script, it fails.